# laravel 7 error in console of http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I try to create chat app in my project laravel 7 but i have syntax error and i dont understand where i search but i dont see. When i check console in http://127.0.0.1:8000/ i have this error

```
SyntaxError: /home/mokoch/projetabonnementpayant/resources/js/components/ChatApp.vue: Unexpected token, expected "{" (12:11)

[0m [90m 10 | [39m[36mimport[39m [33mContactsList[39m from [32m'./ContactsList'[39m[33m;[39m[0m
[0m [90m 11 | [39m[0m
[0m[31m[1m>[22m[39m[90m 12 | [39m    [36mexport[39m defaults {[0m
[0m [90m    | [39m           [31m[1m^[22m[39m[0m
[0m [90m 13 | [39m        data(){[0m
[0m [90m 14 | [39m            [36mreturn[39m {[0m
[0m [90m 15 | [39m                selectedContact[33m:[39m [36mnull[39m[0m
    at Parser._raise (home/mokoch/projetabonnementpayant/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:754)
    at Parser.raiseWithData (home/mokoch/projetabonnementpayant/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:747)
    at Parser.raise (home/mokoch/projetabonnementpayant/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:741)
    at Parser.unexpected (home/mokoch/projetabonnementpayant/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:8844)
    at Parser.parseExport (home/mokoch/projetabonnementpayant/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:12302)
    at Parser.parseStatementContent (home/mokoch/projetabonnementpayant/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11297)
    at Parser.parseStatement (home/mokoch/projetabonnementpayant/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11193)
    at Parser.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody (home/mokoch/projetabonnementpayant/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11768)
    at Parser.parseBlockBody (home/mokoch/projetabonnementpayant/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11754)
    at Parser.parseTopLevel (home/mokoch/projetabonnementpayant/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11124)
    at Parser.parse (home/mokoch/projetabonnementpayant/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:12826)
    at parse (home/mokoch/projetabonnementpayant/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:12879)
    at parser (home/mokoch/projetabonnementpayant/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/parser/index.js:54)
    at parser.next (<anonymous>)
    at normalizeFile (home/mokoch/projetabonnementpayant/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/normalize-file.js:93)
    at normalizeFile.next (<anonymous>)
    at run (home/mokoch/projetabonnementpayant/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/index.js:31)
    at run.next (<anonymous>)
    at Function.transform (home/mokoch/projetabonnementpayant/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transform.js:27)
    at transform.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (home/mokoch/projetabonnementpayant/node_modules/gensync/index.js:254)
    at gen.next (home/mokoch/projetabonnementpayant/node_modules/gensync/index.js:266)
    at async.call.value (home/mokoch/projetabonnementpayant/node_modules/gensync/index.js:216)
    at errback.call (home/mokoch/projetabonnementpayant/node_modules/gensync/index.js:184)
    at runGenerator.errback (home/mokoch/projetabonnementpayant/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/gensync-utils/async.js:72)
    at val (home/mokoch/projetabonnementpayant/node_modules/gensync/index.js:108)
    at step (home/mokoch/projetabonnementpayant/node_modules/gensync/index.js:280)
    at gen.next (home/mokoch/projetabonnementpayant/node_modules/gensync/index.js:266)
    at async.call.value (home/mokoch/projetabonnementpayant/node_modules/gensync/index.js:216)
    at Object../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./resources/js/components/ChatApp.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (app.js:1909)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at Module../resources/js/components/ChatApp.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (app.js:55796)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at Module../resources/js/components/ChatApp.vue (app.js:55759)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at Object../resources/js/app.js (app.js:55687)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at Object.0 (app.js:55839)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
```

I check my chatapp.vue but i cant find error.
this is my ChatApp.vue

```
    <div class="chat-app">
        <Conversation :contact="selectedContact" :messages="messages" @new="saveNewMessage"/>
        <ContactsList :contacts="contacts" @selected="startConversationWith"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    import Conversation from './Conversation';
    import ContactsList from './ContactsList';

    export default {
        props: {
            user: {
                type: Object,
                required: true
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                selectedContact: null,
                messages: [],
                contacts: []
            };
        },
        mounted() {
            Echo.private(`messages.${this.user.id}`)
                .listen('NewMessage', (e) => {
                    this.hanleIncoming(e.message);
                });
            axios.get('/contacts')
                .then((response) => {
                    this.contacts = response.data;
                });
        },
        methods: {
            startConversationWith(contact) {
                this.updateUnreadCount(contact, true);
                axios.get(`/conversation/${contact.id}`)
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.messages = response.data;
                        this.selectedContact = contact;
                    })
            },
            saveNewMessage(message) {
                this.messages.push(message);
            },
            hanleIncoming(message) {
                if (this.selectedContact && message.from == this.selectedContact.id) {
                    this.saveNewMessage(message);
                    return;
                }
                this.updateUnreadCount(message.from_contact, false);
            },
            updateUnreadCount(contact, reset) {
                this.contacts = this.contacts.map((single) => {
                    if (single.id !== contact.id) {
                        return single;
                    }
                    if (reset)
                        single.unread = 0;
                    else
                        single.unread += 1;
                    return single;
                })
            }
        },
        components: {Conversation, ContactsList}
    }
</script>


<style lang="scss" scoped>
.chat-app {
    display: flex;
}
</style>
```

Contactlist.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="contacts-list">
        <ul>
            <li v-for="contact in sortedContacts" :key="contact.id" @click="selectContact(contact)" :class="{ 'selected': contact == selected }">
                <div class="avatar">
                    <img :src="contact.profile_image" :alt="contact.name">
                </div>
                <div class="contact">
                    <p class="name">{{ contact.name }}</p>
                    <p class="email">{{ contact.email }}</p>
                </div>
                <span class="unread" v-if="contact.unread">{{ contact.unread }}</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            contacts: {
                type: Array,
                default: []
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                selected: this.contacts.length ? this.contacts[0] : null
            };
        },
        methods: {
            selectContact(contact) {
                this.selected = contact;
                this.$emit('selected', contact);
            }
        },
        computed: {
            sortedContacts() {
                return _.sortBy(this.contacts, [(contact) => {
                    if (contact == this.selected) {
                        return Infinity;
                    }
                    return contact.unread;
                }]).reverse();
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.contacts-list {
    flex: 2;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    overflow: scroll;
    border-left: 1px solid #a6a6a6;
    
    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding-left: 0;
        li {
            display: flex;
            padding: 2px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
            height: 80px;
            position: relative;
            cursor: pointer;
            &.selected {
                background: #dfdfdf;
            }
            span.unread {
                background: #82e0a8;
                color: #fff;
                position: absolute;
                right: 11px;
                top: 20px;
                display: flex;
                font-weight: 700;
                min-width: 20px;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                line-height: 20px;
                font-size: 12px;
                padding: 0 4px;
                border-radius: 3px;
            }
            .avatar {
                flex: 1;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                img {
                    width: 35px;
                    border-radius: 50%;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                }
            }
            .contact {
                flex: 3;
                font-size: 10px;
                overflow: hidden;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                justify-content: center;
                p {
                    margin: 0;
                    &.name {
                        font-weight: bold;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</style>
```

Someone can talk me where is error? because i'm try to find i don't find. I try to do something other not work now i asked your help because i'm blocked.

Comment: ChatApp.vue: Unexpected token, expected "{" (12:11)

Comment: check your `ContactsList` imported file

Comment: i shared my ContactsList

Answer (score 1):

Change your `data() {}` to something like

```
data: () => ({
     selectedContact: null,
     messages: [],
     contacts: []
}),
```

Data should be a function, you can check here for more info: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function